# Proper way to separate declaration and initialisation of class members

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and having trouble figuring out the proper way to declare and initialise a member variable inside a constructor so that it may be used throughout the rest of the class.

I have a custom class with a public constructor that takes three std::string as paramaters -

e.g. `MyClass client("a", "b", "c");`

Coming from a Java/C# background I'm used to using it in another class like so:

```
public Class Foo
{

  private MyClass client = null;

  public Foo()
  {
    client = new MyClass("a", "b", "c");
  }

  ... [can use MyClass member variable client in methods here]

}
```

How would I go about doing something similar in C++? I have tried putting `MyClass client;` within the private block in my header file, then initialising it within the cpp file like `client("a", "b", "c");` but that doesn't work.

Any examples would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Using member variables directly is not really a best practice, is it? I know there are times it is more convenient to do so, but in my head, doing things that way in Java was always like trying to use a C struct..

Comment: I think I may need to clarify my question description. I don't mean using the members of client (MyClass) throughout methods, I mean being able to use the MyClass instance throughout the methods in Foo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In it's simplest form. You should really do some reading on c++ classes.

```
class Foo
{
    MyClass client;

public: 
    Foo() : client("a", "b", "c") {}
}
```

Comment: Ah, an initializer list. I did read that but forgot, and your syntax threw me at first.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, was just trying to make it a bit more compact :)